# Create RDLC report dynamically at run-time from a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a form `AdvancedSearchForm` with a **DataGridView** control `dgrData` and a button `Report` in C# Winform. On click of the button `Report`, I wish that a form with a **ReportView** control be shown with the same columns as in the DataGridView with the same column Headers.

**Form with DataGridView and Button**

[image]

**Output expected on clicking Button “Report”:**

[image]

My **DatagridView** (`dgrData`) Control is associated with

1. SQL

> ```
> “Select Id, c_Name from Country”
> ```

2. ConnectionString

> ```
> server=localhost;User Id=root;password=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=country_state
> ```

To load data to the grid at runtime, I prepare the following **DataAdapter**:

```
DataAdapter dataAdapter = DataAdapter.Current;
// I am passing the SQL statement and the table name to my database which knows the ConnectionString within the LoadData function

DataTable dt0 = dataAdapter.LoadData("select Id, c_Name from `country`", "country");
if (dt0 != null) {
   dgrData.DataSource = dt0;
}
```

Is it possible to call a child Form containing default **reportviewer** control, which shows report with a table containing columns corresponding to the datagridview (`dgrData`) along with data dynamically at runtime?

**Output expectation in detail:**

1. On click of button, the reportviewer on the target form should get
   associated with the dataSource from the values in the
   **DataGridView**. So, the **ReportViewer** control does not know anything about the data in the report till user clicks on the Report
   Button at run-time.
2. I wish the the solution does not require creation of a separate RDLC
   file, because It causes external dependency, to stop the current flow
   and create a report file in a report file designer which can be
   over-whelming to users.
3. I know nothing about RDLC designer and associating data source (I am
   willing to learn (^_^), but I cannot force this learning requirement
   on my team) and binding the data to the report. I would appreciate
   working coding examples, if your help contains theory.
4. I know ReportViewer has been around for quite a long time now. Wish
   that an example solution for 1-1 data mapping between data-grid and
   ReportViewer was easier to find for someone in the future on SO.

**Note:** Please let me know if any additional data is required from my side in the comments. To show the current solution, I had to create and RDLC file where I had to put both the connection string and SQL at design time which I wish to avoid in the solution I am looking for. I wish to find a solution where the RDLC file is generated through some modular code that can be used on other solutions as well, rather than having to design it for each form where I have DataGrids.

Comment: [Pass DataTable to ReportViewer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34512521/3110834)

Comment: let me try the solution in c# and get back to this chain.

Comment: *I wish the the solution does not require creation of a separate RDLC.* The solution which I posted is based on an existing report. It doesn't create columns at run-time. If you need to create report at run-time, you can use [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479511/display-datasource-from-datagridview-in-reportviewer) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39713817/3110834).

Comment: Thank you @rezaAghaei. I want to know if you can help me with creating a rdlc file at run time instead of HTML like you have shown in the other chain. I had seen the solutions you have provided above, but somehow I think they are complicated and I feel things need not be that complex.

Comment: If there is a way to avoid RDLC or HTML files altogether, that would be even better :)

Comment: As another option you can Print the `DataGridView` control using its `DrawToBitmap` method.

Comment: Creating a dynamic rdlc report at run-time would not be easy.

Comment: Also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010705/printing-datagridview-from-right-to-left) and use the C# example from MSDN. If you needed righ to left, apply the fixes which I posted in answer to the C# code, otherwise the C# example for left to right is OK.

Comment: @rezaAghaei, I wanted to know if you can show that solution in C#, I find VB a little difficult to read and translate. I have not formally coded in that language yet.

Comment: If you mean the [last link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010705/printing-datagridview-from-right-to-left) you can download C# version [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/VBNet-Printing-Example-bc3b0176/file/138098/2/VB.Net%20Printing%20Example.zip)

Comment: I tried out the example, it shows print preview after calculating grid. Is there a way to use this logic to get it to generate RDL file at runtime. I will really appreciate if that can be done...

Comment: You can use the Idea which I used to generate html. It's really elegant solution. Use the idea to create an RDLC report.

Comment: I posted an answer based on the same idea of using t4 template. Using is is really simple and it supports adding dolumns dynamically at run-time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an option to create `RDLC` report dynamically at at run-time, you can use [Run-Time Text Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/run-time-text-generation-with-t4-text-templates?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=vs-2019).

In the below example, I've created a simple grid report that can be used to create report dynamically at run-time. You can dynamically add columns to report and set title, width, header back color for column.

In the example, I've filled the template using a `DataGridView`. But you can use this technique dependent from any kind of contrlol or even use it in web forms.

**Sample Usage - Create and Show Dynamic Report**

To create and show dynamic report it's enough to add some columns to the `ReportForm` and then set data and show the form.

```
var f = new ReportForm();
f.ReportColumns = this.dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                      .Select(x => new ReportColumn(x.DataPropertyName)
                      { Title = x.HeaderText, Width = x.Width }).ToList();
f.ReportData = this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
f.ShowDialog();
```

[image]

## Path to solution

It's enough to add `ReportColumn` and `DynamicReport.tt` and `ReportForm` to your application or even in a reusable library once and then simply use like above example. Follow below steps to create a dynamic report template.

**Report Column Model**

Create a report column model that contains properties for title, expression, color and so on. We will use this to add columns to report.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
public class ReportColumn
{
    public ReportColumn(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Title = name;
        Type = typeof(System.String);
        Width = GetPixelFromInch(1);
        Expression = string.Format("=Fields!{0}.Value", name);
        HeaderBackColor = Color.LightGray;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public float WidthInInch
    {
        get { return GetInchFromPixel(Width); }
    }
    public string Expression { get; set; }
    public Color HeaderBackColor { get; set; }
    public string HeaderBackColorInHtml
    {
        get { return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(HeaderBackColor); }
    }
    private int GetPixelFromInch(float inch)
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
            return (int)(g.DpiY * inch);
    }
    private float GetInchFromPixel(int pixel)
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
            return (float)pixel / g.DpiY;
    }
}
```

**Report Template**

Add a Run-time Template (Also known as Preprocessed template) to the project and name it `DynamicReport.tt` and copy this content to the file:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ parameter name="Model" type="System.Collections.Generic.List<ReportColumn>"#>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>System.Data.DataSet</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>/* Local Connection */</ConnectString>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:DataSourceID>e9784bb0-a630-49cc-b7f9-8495aca23a6c</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Fields>
<#    foreach(ReportColumn column in Model){#>
        <Field Name="<#=column.Name#>">
          <DataField><#=column.Name#></DataField>
          <rd:TypeName><#=column.Type.Name#></rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
<#    }#>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <rd:DataSetInfo>
        <rd:DataSetName />
        <rd:TableName />
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceType />
      </rd:DataSetInfo>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
        <TablixBody>
          <TablixColumns>
<#    foreach(ReportColumn column in Model){#>
            <TablixColumn>
              <Width><#=column.WidthInInch#>in</Width>
            </TablixColumn>
<#    }#>
          </TablixColumns>
          <TablixRows>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
<#    foreach(ReportColumn column in Model){#>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="<#=column.Name#>TextBox">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value><#=column.Title#></Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName><#=column.Name#>TextBox</rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <BackgroundColor><#=column.HeaderBackColorInHtml#></BackgroundColor>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
<#    }#>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
            <TablixRow>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <TablixCells>
<#    foreach(ReportColumn column in Model){#>
                <TablixCell>
                  <CellContents>
                    <Textbox Name="<#=column.Name#>">
                      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                      <Paragraphs>
                        <Paragraph>
                          <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                              <Value><#=column.Expression#></Value>
                              <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                          </TextRuns>
                          <Style />
                        </Paragraph>
                      </Paragraphs>
                      <rd:DefaultName><#=column.Name#></rd:DefaultName>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                          <Style>Solid</Style>
                        </Border>
                        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                      </Style>
                    </Textbox>
                  </CellContents>
                </TablixCell>
<#    }#>
              </TablixCells>
            </TablixRow>
          </TablixRows>
        </TablixBody>
        <TablixColumnHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
<#    foreach(ReportColumn column in Model){#>
            <TablixMember />
<#    }#>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixRowHierarchy>
          <TablixMembers>
            <TablixMember>
              <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
            </TablixMember>
            <TablixMember>
              <Group Name="Details" />
            </TablixMember>
          </TablixMembers>
        </TablixRowHierarchy>
        <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
        <Top>0.15625in</Top>
        <Left>0.125in</Left>
        <Height>0.5in</Height>
        <Width>2in</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Tablix>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>0.82292in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>6.5in</Width>
  <Page>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <rd:ReportID>60987c40-62b1-463b-b670-f3fa81914e33</rd:ReportID>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
</Report>
```

**Report Form**

Add a `Form` to project and add a `ReportViewer` control to the form and put this code in the class:

```
public partial class ReportForm : Form
{
    public ReportForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReportColumns  = new List<ReportColumn>();
        this.Load+=new EventHandler(ReportForm_Load);
    }

    public List<ReportColumn> ReportColumns { get; set; }
    public Object ReportData { get; set; }

    private void ReportForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var report = new DynamicReport();
        report.Session = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        report.Session["Model"] = this.ReportColumns;
        report.Initialize();
        var rds = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", this.ReportData);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        var reportContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(report.TransformText());
        using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(reportContent))
        {
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
        }
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
}
```

**Note**

You can simply extend the `ReportColumn` model and also `DynamicReport.tt`. I've created the template using an exiting report, I just used some t4 code tags to make it dynamic.

**Example**

You can clone or download a working example:

- [r-aghaei/DynamicRdlcReport](https://github.com/r-aghaei/DynamicRdlcReport)
- [Download Zip](https://github.com/r-aghaei/DynamicRdlcReport/archive/master.zip)

Comment: thank you, this seems to mimic the DataGrid exactly and solves the problem for now. I wanted to know if there is flexibility in the Pre-processor template to make it appear in a more custom format. Specifically in cases where we need to merge rows and columns as per our reporting needs.

Comment: Can we set different grid widths to different columns in this type of pre-processor template for data we have on the grid?

Comment: the .tt file shown above seems to be XML, could you show a HTML implementation of the same please. . .

Comment: I need help with the following lines <br/> 
            f.ReportColumns = this.dgrData.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                .Select(x => new ReportColumn(x.DataPropertyName) { Title = x.HeaderText, Width = x.Width }).ToList();

Comment: can you please convert this to code without lambda expression please

Comment: This is the way that t4 works: The `tt` file works as a template. It converts all lines to `Writer.Write("...")` methods and mixes the `C#` code which we used in `tt`. Then as a result it creates a `C#` class which has some methods like `TransformText` which creates the string output for us. Somehow it works like ASP.NET pages which you mix texts and C# code blocks or like Razor. The C# class is generated under `tt` file in solution and should not be touched. Make any changes in `tt` file then the C# class will changes. To learn more about T4 templates see the linked document from Microsoft.

Comment: RDLC report is in fact a XML file that used by Report Engine to render. It doesn't have anything to do with HTML. The RDLC which you see in the T4 file, is not a magical one, I created a simple table report and then used its XML in T4 file. Then instead of having columns hard-coded, I created them using those `foreach` loops which you see in the T4 file. To add other elements like a title or a footer or some labels for date time and so on, yo should use the same Idea and create a report and convert it to such T4 template.

Comment: You can add columns with different widths to the `ReportColumns`. The can be different from `DataGridView` columns. But you should provide data for that column. For example you can use it this way: `f.ReportColumns.Add(new ReportColumn("A"));f.ReportColumns.Add(new ReportColumn("B"));` then you can pass a `List` which its elements contains `A` and `B` properties. For example a `DataTable` which is created this way: `var dt = new DataTable(); dt.Columns.Add("A"); dt.Columns.Add("B"); dt.Rows.Add("1");dt.Rows.Add("2");` then if you set `f.ReportData = dt` it shows the report with these data.

Comment: oh wonderful. I also figured out how the lambda function works. For my own code, i changed the block above to:            List<ReportColumn> lstRepCmn = new List<ReportColumn>();
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dgrData.Columns) {
                if (c.Visible) {
                    ReportColumn r = new ReportColumn(c.DataPropertyName) { Title = c.HeaderText, Width = c.Width };
                    lstRepCmn.Add(r);
                }
            }f.ReportColumns = lstRepCmn;

Comment: Using `Linq` is optional but it;s essential and you should not avoid using linq. The code which I used is equivalent to a simple `foreach` loop. `var list = new List<ReportColumn>(); foreach(DataGridViewRow x in dataGridView1.Rows){ list.Add(new ReportColumn(x.DataPropertyName) { Title = x.HeaderText, Width = x.Width });}` Then `f.ReportColumns = list;`.

Comment: Yes, great. Linq is really useful.

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei, I will contact you further on this if i come across any more doubts. Thank you very much for being patient with this problem and helping me with reportViewer control.

Comment: I can see from the code that this ultimately creates RDL file syntax at run time that can be loaded to a report viewer. Is there a way I can see the generated RDL syntax code?

Comment: the `reportContent` variable is the string which contains `RDLC` format. Save it to a `*.rdlc` file then you can simply open it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Creating dynamic reports at run-time is not easy and in a real world environment/project I believe my answer here is just a start point. But a really elegant and useful solution. If you get the idea, it will be useful for you for many cases which you need to create templates, for example an email template which contains the products which the customer has bought. The idea is brilliant IMO!

Comment: Also the `HTML` answer which I [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39713817/3110834) is really good start point for those who wants to create HTML output, but most users doesn't have any idea about Run-time T4 Templates and don't know how it works and since the answer is somehow long the answer is neglected; but it's really useful indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the note on reportContent variable. I will go through the HTML part as well. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Let me know if you had any question about the linked post or if you find it useful :)

Comment: can we get the RDL Skeleton from this? I have got the xml generated from the report content using the code `string RDLCCode = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reportContent);` but can get the design schema?

Comment: You should first feed the template with model and (ReportColumns) and initialize it then you can write `var reportContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(report.TransformText());` then `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\report1.rdlc", reportContent );`

Comment: Can you show me what changes I need to do. To me it looks like the model assignment and reportContent serialization happend in the same file - ReportForm.cs. However, I dont know how to get the RDL skeleton from this

Comment: I think if you paste all the comments above into one comprehensive learning answer, it will weight as much as the answer itself (^_^)

Comment: You're right. But the answer is long enough and it makes the answer too much long, most users don't read the answer currently if I make it more longer probably it decreases the chance of the answer to be read. Insteaf you can vote the comments which you think are more useful to bring them up.

Comment: I have posted a separate question to seek answers regarding RDL report generation in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395159/c-sharp-winform-how-to-generate-real-time-reports-by-passing-3-variables-to-re .

Comment: I found this post really useful! I just wondered if Reza Agaei could help me to include grouping and sorting? I have posted a new related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373578/how-to-use-run-time-text-templates-to-do-report-grouping-and-sorting)